# Determining the Role of “As” in Titles

Tags: capitalization, parts-of-speech

Could you give me some tips on how to determine the role of the word “as” in titles so that I can see whether to capitalize it or not?

What kind of role does it have in idioms like *as is*, *as if*, and *as it were*?

I presume that no matter what part of speech a word belongs to, it gets capitalized when between quotation marks, such as in the title of this question. Is that correct? Is that comma after *to* and before *it* correct, or should it be removed?

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the title you are working on.

Comment: What @jera said. I'm having trouble imagining contexts where *as it were* might occur in a "title".

Comment: There are no universal rules for punctuation of titles.